# Android Blackberry: How to render view within app using blackberry access

Tags: android, blackberry

I know how to launch access browser from my app but need to know how to render view within my app using blackberry access for Android which is one of the method blackberry lists for web view options. I had tried open http method from web view but it launches new access browser instance. Blackberry docs say this option is available since March 2020 in android access browser versions.

this option is listed in the first way of using webviews using access browser in below blog but there is no example on how to do it.

https://devblog.blackberry.com/en/2020/04/webviews-in-blackberry-dynamics-android-applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already using the Open HTTP URL BlackBerry Dynamics Shared Service to open BlackBerry Access, you are almost there.  All you need to do is add the 'fullscreen' parameter to your JSON and set it to true.  Optionally you can also set the 'showlauncher' parameter to control whether the BlackBerry Launcher icon appears on top of the web view or not.  You can find the JSON definition here:  https://marketplace.blackberry.com/services/795018

Comment: Thanks I already have full screen with launcher. But my problem is the service call opens access in  seperate window not In the current window of my app. I am also new in android programming and calling service call from web view.

Comment: It will open in its own Activity, so you can't have the full screen BlackBerry Access web view on the screen at the same time as other UI elements (buttons, etc).  But the screen should reside within your application and not BlackBerry Access.  Try using the task switcher to check this.  If you wish have the web view appear as a control within your own screen, you'd need to use the approach taken in this sample (which doesn't use BlackBerry Access):  https://github.com/blackberry/BlackBerry-Dynamics-Android-Samples/tree/master/AndroidWebView